# request.user in decorators.py returns different results to self.request.user in views.py

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, decorator, django-class-based-views

I have created a decorator 'unauthenticated_user(view_func)' in my 'decorators.py' file which restricts a user from accessing a view if the current user is not authenticated.

In the 'unauthenticated_user()' function, there is a conditional 'request.user.is_authenticated' which should return true if a user attached to the token is authenticated. However, upon testing this function, I have noticed that 'request.user' in 'decorators.py' is not always equal to the correct value returned by 'self.request.user' in 'views.py'. Instead, it often returns previously logged in users, or 'AnonymousUser' which ruins functionality.

**decorators.py:**

```
def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('No user logged in')

    return wrapper_func
```

**views.py:**

```
@method_decorator(unauthenticated_user, name = 'dispatch')
class UserLogout(APIView):
    ...
```

This is the views.py function I have been using to test that there is in fact an authenticated user when the decorators.py function returns 'AnonymousUser':

```
class Current(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format = None):
        try:
            return Response(self.request.user.is_authenticated)
        except:
            return Response("no user currently logged in")
```

How to I ensure that 'decorators.py' 'unauthenticated_user' function has access to the user in the current request like the 'Current' view does in 'views.py'?

Any help would be much appreciated. To my knowledge there is no way to call 'self' in the 'decorators.py' function.

Thanks, Grae

Comment: Perhaps you could use `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]` instead of your decorator - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the DRF, you should make use of the [***`IsAuthenticated`***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated) permission class of the view

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({"msg": "Some message"})
```

Comment: How would I go about making custom permissions like I can in 'decorators.py'?

Comment: Refer [DRF Custom permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)